# How to construct such generic class?

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Matrix<TValue, TList extends List<E>> {
    private TList<TList<TValue>> items;
}
```

I want to use 2 instances of `Matrix` class. One with `ArrayList<Integer>` and second with `LinkedList<Integer>`.

Comment: It is hard to get your text and code together. It may help when you provide code for two classes where one class is using `ArrayLists` and the other `LinkedLists` but doing the same. Then ask how to solve this with generics and having only one generic class then. In it's current state your question is in fact not a question and very unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is very difficult to code a generic object wich contains a list of lists the way you want to.

This is because of type erasure in java wich means:

```
LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<Integer>();
assert(ll.getClass() == LinkedList.class); // this is always true

LinkedList<String> ll_string = new LinkedList<String>();
assert(ll.getClass() == ll_string.getClass()); // this is also always true
```

However, if the types of lists you want to use is small, you can do something similar to this example (this one is limited to ArrayList and LinkedList):

```
public class Matrix <TValue> {

    Object items = null;

    public <TContainer> Matrix(Class<TContainer> containerClass) throws Exception{       
        try{
            TContainer obj = containerClass.newInstance();

            if(obj instanceof ArrayList){
                items = new ArrayList<ArrayList<TValue>>();
            } else if(obj instanceof LinkedList){
                items = new LinkedList<LinkedList<TValue>>();
            }                                 
        }catch(Exception ie){
            throw new Exception("The matrix container could not be intialized." );
        }                       
        if(items == null){
            throw new Exception("The provided container class is not ArrayList nor LinkedList");
        }
    }


    public List<List<TValue>> getItems(){
        return (List<List<TValue>>)items;
    }


}
```

This can be easily initialized and used:

```
try {
        Matrix<Integer> m_ArrayList = new Matrix<Integer>(ArrayList.class);
        Matrix<Integer> m_LinkedList = new Matrix<Integer>(LinkedList.class);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();;
    }
```

Comment: +1 I was just trying to come up with a clear way of explaining this, though the OP is prob still going to be confused. :)

Comment: it seems to be really no good way to code this :( by the way, thanks for explanation